# Nvidia drivers don't work on ubuntu 20.04 with 5.15.0-051500rc7 kernel

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, graphics, games

I have a problem the nvidia-smi doesn't work as in the first picture and the NVIDIA X Server Settings is opening empty as in the second image.I had to upgrade my kernel do to the network adapter problem and since then the Nvidia X Server Settings is empty. My kernel is 5.15.0-051500rc7-generic on ubuntu 20.04. I have a GTX 1650 on a laptop, I have tried to do the prime-select nvidia shows me: "Info: the nvidia profile is already set".  What can I do in this situation to make my drivers visible, because when I am in a game doesn't see them, as in the 3rd picture.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like you asked this already. Asking the same question another time won't add anything.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is obvious. Nvidia proprietary drives don't support unrealeased kernel versions. And even released versions are not supported immediately after a kernel release. You can see which kernels are supported in their release notes.

Comment: yes, sorry! I did not see my old question so I asked again sorry